# How to fit a stand model with two nested multiplications to mu

Tags: regression, bayesian, python, modeling, stan

I'm studying the *Statistical Rethinking 2ed* book and trying to write the codes to Stan (I'm using pystan). And stuck on how to write the model below in stan.

This problem is described in the book page $172$ and $173$ - RCode $6.16$

#### Generating the data:

```
# number of plants
N = 100

# Initial simulation of heights
h0 = np.random.normal(10, 2, N)

# Assigning treatments and simulating fungi and treatments
treatment = np.repeat([0,1], repeats=int(N/2))
fungus = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=(0.5 - treatment*0.4), size=N)

# Final plant height
h1 = h0 + np.random.normal(5 - 3*fungus, 1, N) 

# Dataframe
d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'h0': h0,  
                            'h1': h1, 
                            'treatment': treatment, 
                            'fungus': fungus})
```

Math model (*post-treatment bias*) is:

$$ h_{1, i} \sim Normal(\mu_i, \sigma) $$

$$ \mu_i = h_{0, i} \times p $$

$$ p = \alpha + \beta_T T_i + \beta_F F_i $$

prioris:

$$ \alpha \sim LogNormal(0, 0.25) $$

$$ \beta_T \sim Normal(0, 0.5) $$

$$ \beta_F \sim Normal(0, 0.5) $$

$$ \sigma \sim Exponential(1) $$

I tried writing the model in a few ways and was unsuccessful, this was the best attempt I could think of.

```
model = """
    data {
        int N;
        vector[N] h0;
        vector[N] h1;
        vector[N] T;  // Treatment
        vector[N] F;  // Fungus
    }

    parameters {
        real<lower=0> alpha;
        real bT;
        real bF;
        real<lower=0> sigma;
    }

    model {
        alpha ~ lognormal(0, 0.25);
        bT ~ normal(0, 0.5);
        bF ~ normal(0, 0.5);
        sigma ~ exponential(1);
        
        for (n in 1:N){
            h1[n] ~ normal((alpha + bF*F + bT*T) * h0[n], sigma);
        }
    }
"""

data = {
    'N': N,
    'h0': h0,
    'h1': h1,
    'T': treatment,
    'F': fungus,
}

posteriori = stan.build(model, data=data)
samples = posteriori.sample(num_chains=4, num_samples=1000)
```

##### The expected result:

|  | mean | std |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alpha | 1.38 | 0.02 |
| bT | 0.00 | 0.03 |
| bF | -0.27 | 0.04 |
| sigma | 1.41 | 0.10 |

##### My result was:

|  | mean | std |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alpha | 1.44 | 0.00 |
| bT | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| bF | -0.00 | 0.00 |
| sigma | 1.67 | 0.01 |

The average slopes of my model from the betas *are always* $0$.

Can someone explain to me a way to write this model in Stan or point me to a place I can look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That model resolve the problem:

```
    data {
        int N;
        vector[N] h0;
        vector[N] h1;
        vector[N] T;  // Treatment
        vector[N] F;  // Fungus
    }

    parameters {
        real alpha;
        real bT;
        real bF;
        real<lower=0> sigma;
    }

    model {
        vector[N] mu;
        vector[N] p;
        
        p = alpha + bT * T + bF * F;
        mu = h0 .* p;  
    
        // likelihood
        h1 ~ normal(mu, sigma);
    
        // prioris
        alpha ~ lognormal(0, 0.25);
        bT ~ normal(0, 0.5);
        bF ~ normal(0, 0.5);
        sigma ~ exponential(1);
    }
```

In stan docs:

```
vector[N] a;
vector[N] b;
vector[N] c; 

These operation:
c = a .* b;

Is the same operation:
for (n in 1:N) {
  c[n] = a[n] * b[n];
}
```

Reference: https://mc-stan.org/docs/reference-manual/arithmetic-expressions.html